# Why the polynomial field $f(x)$ of $r$ is in $P'$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

Let $D$ be a Dedekind domain, $F$ its field of fractions, $E$ a finite dimensional extension field of $F$ and $D'$ the subring of $E$ of $D$ integral elements. Assume that $E/F$ is a finite separable field extension.

Let $P'$ be a prime ideal in $D'$ and let $r$ be a non-zero element in $P'$. Then $f(r)=0$ for the polynomial field $f(x)$ of $r$. Why does it follow that $f(x)$ is in $P'$?

Would you help, me, please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't get what is $f(x)$ ? Is it a minimal polynomial of something ?

Comment: $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial  of $r$ over $F$ i suppose

Comment: $f(x)$ is the splitting polynomial of $r$ over $F$; it is a power of the minimum polynomial.

Comment: Did you mean $f(0) \in P'$ and $f(P') \subset P'$ ? In that case this is because $f(x) = \prod_{\sigma \in Gal(N/F)} (x-\sigma(r))$ where $N/E/F$ is the Galois closure.